# How to add two float fields with different currency sign?

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11

We have already Amount field on invoice lines which shows the amount in the currency selected on invoice. I want to convert the same amount to base currency and also show the base currency amount on invoice lines with base currency symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose I have added new many2one field for base currency as show below:

```
base_currency_id = fields.Many2one('res.currency', default=lambda self: self.invoice_id.company_id.currency_id.id)
```

Then I added new float field for computing the amount in base currency like this:

```
@api.onchange('price_subtotal', 'invoice_id.currency_id')
def compute_amount_in_base_currency(self):
    company_currency = self.invoice_id.company_id.currency_id
    for l in self:
        amount_in_base = l.currency_id.compute(l.price_subtotal, company_currency)
        l.amount_in_base = amount_in_base

amount_in_base = fields.Float('Base Amount', readonly=True, compute='compute_amount_in_base_currency')
```

In xml file I have added `base_currency_id` field and made it invisible. Then added `amount_in_base` field to the view with `widget='monetary'` and `options="{'currency_field': 'base_currency_id'}"`. My xml file looks like this:

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='invoice_line_ids']/tree/field[@name='price_subtotal']" position="after">
    <field name="base_currency_id" invisible="True"/>
    <field name="amount_in_base" widget="monetary" options="{'currency_field': 'base_currency_id'}"/>
</xpath>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use the invoice's company currency instead of the user's company currency? Because users can switch the company. And use `depends` instead of `onchange`.